# How to generate back to back chart in D3?

Tags: python, matplotlib, d3.js, visualization, altair

I am using Matplotlib for a back to back plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# create data
A = np.array([3,6,9,4,2,5])
B = np.array([2,8,1,9,7,3])
X = np.arange(6)
  
# plot the bars
plt.barh(X, A, align='center',
         alpha=0.9, color = 'y')
  
plt.barh(X, -B, align='center', 
         alpha=0.6, color = 'c')
plt.yticks([0, 1, 2,3,4,5], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])
plt.xticks([], [])


plt.show()
```

I am wondering how to generate d3 code using python?
Is Altair the right option?

Comment: Just to clarify: do you want to create d3 *code* or simply use a visualization library that is built on top of d3? If it is the latter, then Altair is a good choice, it wraps Vega-Lite, which is built on top of Vega, which in turn is built on top of D3 https://vega.github.io/vega/about/vega-and-d3/. You can see what Vega-Lite and Vega code looks like here https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega-lite/bar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of generating a similar chart with Altair:

```python
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

df = pd.DataFrame({
  "A": np.array([3,6,9,4,2,5]),
  "B": np.array([2,8,1,9,7,3]),
  "X": ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
})

alt.Chart(df).transform_calculate(
    A=-alt.datum.A  
).transform_fold(
    ["A", "B"], as_=["key", "value"]
).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X("value:Q", axis=None),
    y='X:N',
    color="key:N"
).properties(
    width=300,
    height=200
)
```

[image]